# Load javascript from file in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, read-eval-print-loop

I am try loading a simple js file on the node.js console and it never shows me the result. I have a test.js file with a single line: `console.log("testing");` 
If I enter directly the command into the console it works but by doing node test.js it shows me `...` loading.

Comment: Could you please add your full code? Do you see any error message?

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to invoke the command `node test.js` when already inside the [REPL](http://nodejs.org/api/repl.html) (the node.js console as you put it). The REPL only accepts JavaScript.

The command `node test.js` within the REPL is therefore a JavaScript syntax error, however the REPL attempts to recover from syntax errors by buffering the command and prompting you for more input (i.e. `...`). See [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/repl.js#L297-L307) in the REPL code.

You can either

- Exit the REPL and from your terminal/console provide the test file as an argument to the node executable, i.e. `node test.js` (as I think you were intending to do)

Or as @JonathanLonowski suggests, within the REPL you can use:

- [`require('./test')`](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_require)
- [`child_process.fork('./test'`)](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options)

(When starting the node REPL in the directory where the test file is)

Comment: Or use either [`require('./test')`](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_require) or [`child_process.fork('./test')`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options) while in the REPL.